# Twisted sheaf isomorphic to invertible sheaf associated to 1-cocycle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X=\operatorname{Proj}A$ for some graded ring $A$ such that the irrelevant ideal $A_+$ is generated by the degree one part $A_1$ of $A$.
Then Bosch's $\textit{Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra}$ states on page $427$: taking generators $f_i\in A_1$ of $A_+$ and letting $\eta_{ij}=f_i^n/f_j^n$, this defines a 1-cocycle (with respect to the cover $\{D_+(f_i)\}$), whose associated invertible sheaf $\mathcal{F}$is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$.

My question is: What does the isomorphism look like? I first thought of gluing the isomorphisms $$\phi_i\colon \mathcal{O}_X(n)\vert_{D_+(f_i)}\cong \mathcal{O}_X\vert_{D_+(f_i)}\cong \mathcal{F}\vert_{D_+(f_i)}$$
but these do not seem to agree on overlaps. So, what's the isomorphism Bosch means? I can't think of any other one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Think of them as transition functions. Therefore your line bundle can be described (upto isomorphism) as the locally free sheaf of module generated by $f_i^n$ over $D_{+} (f_i)$. But that is equal to $\mathcal {O}_X(n)$.

[ Because, $\mathcal O _X(n) | _{D_{+}(f_i)}= f_i^n p$, where $p \in \mathcal O _X ({D_{+}(f_i)})$. So

$\mathcal O _X(n) | _{D_{+}(f_i f_j)}= f_i^np = f_j^n \left(\frac{f_i^n}{f_j^n}\right)p$. ]